# Display a diamond with <pre> tag

Tags: html

When I display a diamond using HTML `<pre>`, in Sublime it looks fine:

```
<pre>
   *
  ***
 *****
  ***
   *
</pre>
```

But in the browser it looks weird:

[image: browser_display]

Why did this happen?
How could I get it looks right?

Comment: Because you're not using a monospaced font.

Comment: just use `pre {font-family: monospace;}` as per @deceze comment

Comment: Thanks for the help, it turns out my sublime is not using monospace but Consolas, if I change the editor's settings it works fine. But if I change the css rule for the font-family to be Consolas the issue still exists...Is it possible to keep it as Consolas while on Chrome let it display as it is expected? @deceze